# Defining dimension of an array in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, dimension

I am reading number of rows and columns for a matrix 'A' from file-'var_and_runs.txt'
But it shows compilation error - 'unexpected data declaration statement'

```
implicit none
integer i, var, runs
integer  rows, cols
open(unit = 30, file = 'var_and_runs.txt')
    read(30,*) cols,rows

INTEGER, DIMENSION(:, :), ALLOCATABLE :: A

ALLOCATE (A(rows, cols))

open (unit = 40, file = 'read_this.txt')

read(40,*) A
A = transpose(A)
do 80 i = 1,3             
print*, A(i,:)
80    continue
print*, A
end
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have any variable declarations after executable statements. In your case you should replace

```
open(unit = 30, file = 'var_and_runs.txt')
  read(30,*) cols,rows

INTEGER, DIMENSION(:, :), ALLOCATABLE :: A
```

with

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(:, :), ALLOCATABLE :: A
open(unit = 30, file = 'var_and_runs.txt')
  read(30,*) cols,rows
```

and hopefully everything should work fine.

Comment: Thanx, that solved my problem.

Comment: @curiousprogrammer Glad I could help, as this has answered your question it would be useful if you could accept the best answer so that others can see this has been solved (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).